# Firestore Rules Simulator – Error running simulation — Error: simulator.rules line [y], column [x]. Null value error

Tags: database, firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

#### Goal

I am trying to allow read access on any document within the submissions collection with a particular formID (this is just for testing purposes). Example: `/websites/{siteID}/submissions/{submissionID}`

#### Issue

In the simulator it gives me an error when this function is called:

```
function isDocumentOwner(request, resource) {
  return request.auth.uid == resource.data.ownerID;
}
```

The error says: `Error running simulation — Error: simulator.rules line [y], column [x]. Null value error.` (x and y are placeholders referring `r` in `request.auth.uid`)

Before adding `|| resource.data.formID == 'exampleFormID'` the function never caused any issues.

#### Code

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // By default all documents are not allowed to be read or written.
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }

    // ...

    match /websites/{siteID} {
      allow get;
      allow list: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.memberList || isAdmin(request);
      allow write: if isAdmin(request);
      
      // ...

      match /submissions/{submissionID} {
        allow create;

        // This is the line apparently causing the issue
        allow read: if isDocumentOwner(request, resource) || isMember(request, siteID) || isAdmin(request) || resource.data.formID == 'exampleFormID';

        allow update, delete: if isDocumentOwner(request, resource) || isAdmin(request);
      }

    // ...

    // Reusable Security Rule Functions

    function isDocumentOwner(request, resource) {
        return request.auth.uid == resource.data.ownerID;
    }

    // ...

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what's causing the issue still, but switching the order of the `if` statement works.

```
allow read: if resource.data.formID == 'exampleFormID' || isDocumentOwner(request, resource) || isMember(request, siteID) || isAdmin(request);
```

Now the simulator says accessing the documents with the formID works, but it doesn't work in localhost.